# Animation doesn't work

Tags: ios, animation, layer

I have a problem with an animation.
The problem is that if I try to animate a view that is already created all goes well, if I try to create and animate a view at the same time the animation doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

**My Methods**

```
+ (LoginView *)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (nil == _sharedInstance) {
            _sharedInstance = (LoginView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoginView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (void)hide:(BOOL)value animated:(BOOL)animated {
    CATransition * animation = [CATransition animation];

    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    [animation setDuration:1.0];

    if(_autoManageModalView)
        [animation setDelegate:self];

    [[self layer] removeAllAnimations];
    [[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];

    self.hidden = value;
}
```

**How I call them**

```
[[LoginView sharedInstance] hide:NO animated:YES];
```

The first time (with the same call) animation doesn't work, from the secondo time all goes well. Thank in advance!

Comment: Where are you displaying the view? like doing `addSubview:[LoginView sharedInstance]` or whatever?

Comment: a) It's not visible where you are adding it as a view or subview and "create and animate a view at the same time" is not clear b) Your singleton instance might be set to nil and reallocated

Comment: @A-Live - A) is hidden by default (I set it on "awakeFromNib" method). "create and animate a view at the same time" means that the first time a call the hide method, my app create a new instance of the LoginView and, ended with creation, it is supposed to begin the animation; the second time LoginView is already created, so no need to create it and it must be only displayed. B) Why can't I use a singleton?

Comment: @sergio - I display the view when it's created (in the awakeFormNib method).

Comment: @Marco Pace of course you can, but you're better to make it safe considering the multithread usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are animating your view too early in its lifecycle. In theory, you create a view, then display it somewhere (e.g., `addSubview:`), then you animate it.

It is highly possible, though I have not checked it, that the first time that your `hide:animated:` method is called the `self.layer` property is null; in any case, the animation would happen *before* the view is displayed, so you would not see it.

All in all, first display the view, then call the `hide:animated:` method on it.

After your comment: try and call the `hide:animated:` method through a method like:

```
 performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
```

If you specify a 0.0 delay, this will simply queue the call to `hide:animate:` on the main loop, so that all the processing related to `loadNibNamed:` can happen and so give your view the time to be set up for display correctly.

In order to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` you will need to modify your method signature so that it takes one argument and this must be an NSObject-derived type, not a primitive type.

Comment: Please, check my edit, you possibly need to call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly - and I've learned something more!

Comment: Just to end with it: the problem is not that my self.layer is null, the problem (after some reading) is that every UI method is like a wrapper on a "performSelector" method. In may case I did a "hidden = no", so it was performed at the end of my methods after the animation.
Doing a "performSelector" put the animation in the queue after the hidde = no, so it worked :-)